# Hashtag using jquery

Tags: jquery, hashtag

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/Jqfsn/2/). I want h2 name as hashtag and also update hashtag when i click next button. Any one have solution please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/Jqfsn/4/

It actually works with `location.hash`, only not in jsFiddle, probably because it uses an IFrame or something to run the page in.

Comment: One more thing is if i refresh my page, it start from initial. Is this possible to get the same Content after refresh too ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to capture the on load event and check the hash to select the right heading right away. But I think you should also investigate PushState. It's the future, though not supported by IE9 yet.